# Diff on XML with unicode using python

Tags: python, xml, unicode, diff, difflib

I'm trying to create a web tool that can visualize the differences between two XMLs. `difflib` was working pretty well in creating html with the differences, but then some unicode text showed up in the XMLs and the resulting html now contains html-encoded letters.

Is there any other approach to this problem?

Comment: What's wrong with unicode in your XML and html encoded characters in your HTML? Why does that block you?

Answer (score 1):

i assume what bothers you are 'html *character* entities', not their numerical counterparts. you may re-map them e.g. by means of your favorite cli tool supporting regexes (eg. sed) and the tables from [unicode e-workers](http://unicode.e-workers.de/entities.php) or the [reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/entities.html). the numerical entity encoding may be used in html and xml files alike.

best regards, carsten